# Are subdomains covered under PCI?

Tags: subdomain, pci-dss, pci-compliance

I have been asked to set up some registration forms for clients that will take payments, similar to this site (https://www.martialartstechnologies.com/register?tournamentID=82). I am a reseller for Authorize.net, but I find it hard to sign clients up sometimes after they find out they need to get PCI compliant. I was thinking of creating one site domain that is PCI Compliant and then running each clients registration page in their own personal subdomain. If I do this, will the PCI compliance on the domain become invalid for each subdomain, or will it still be covered?

Answer (score 1):

Only **company** can be PCI compliant, not a server, a site, a particular script, a domain or subdomain name. Whole infrastructure, including such things as office WiFi networks and cabinet locks is being audited. You can't trick the auditor painting a cabinet in a different color and claiming it is not yours.

Even if you got 1000 domain names - and they are pointed to 1000 servers located in 1000 places all over the Earth - you must list them all for PCI audit and make them all PCI compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Subdomains can be on different servers, so the first question to answer would be 'same or different servers'?  If on different servers and handling credit card info, you would need to make each server PCI compliant regardless.

Answer (score 0):

PCI compliance deals with the question of code/infrastructure. 
You cannot, as suggested, automatically extend it to sub-domains - even if the main domain is compliant.

Still, if you use the same infrastructure for all sub-domain, you can take care of code related vulnerabilities or just envelope the whole structure in a PCI DDS compliant WAF (I suggest Cloud PCI DDS compliant WAF to cut costs).